# Ngx: Which UrlTree constructor should be used?

Tags: angular

I would like to create an instance of an UrlTree (Angular v14):

According to the
[source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7d3df4724d2baf087453d317ab6ab893d4a7b85f/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L195) of the constructor
or
[the documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree#constructor), I was expecting to do it as follow:

```js
const anUrlTree = new UrlTree(root, someParams, aFragment);
```

However, the imported `UrlTree` class from `'@angular/router';` has no constructor, meaning the signature has no argument.

```js
export declare class UrlTree {
    /** The root segment group of the URL tree */
    root: UrlSegmentGroup;
    /** The query params of the URL */
    queryParams: Params;
    /** The fragment of the URL */
    fragment: string | null;
    get queryParamMap(): ParamMap;
    /** @docsNotRequired */
    toString(): string;
}
```

I therefore had to use the following workaround:

```js
    const nextTree = new UrlTree();
    urlTree.root = root;
    urlTree.queryParams = someParams;
    urlTree.fragment = aFragment;
```

Otherwise, passing arguments to the constructor will raise an error

> TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 3

So here is my question: where is the constructor with arguments gone ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay got it… the constructor's arguments [just have been added](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5163e3d876cdfd6d309d7e35aefa6f07ef62715e#diff-b66b8d89f0c8effbe51128387af21d4705a974d132a64ac6c73090cc73ff2905R1036-R1039) (12 days ago from writing the question)